# What are the UX implications of putting a web link in a mobile app's navigation menu?

Tags: mobile-application, hyperlinks

I've been asked to add a link to a third party website within the main nav menu of our mobile apps. We sell our core products within the app, but other fringe products are sold through a third party website. This sounds like a bad idea to me, but I don't have any concrete reasoning other than "web links don't go in the app navigation, because they aren't part of the app."

Are there specific issues we may be introducing if we proceed with this change?

Might adding some form of external link icon to the menu item suffice?

Comment: This largely depends on the ultimate goal, in marketing terms, of the app. The goal of the app could be to sell more products, in which case it's a great idea to add the link. Alternatively, if the apps main purpose is to drive more engagement with the user then it could be a bad idea for a whole number of reasons. Could you add a little detail about the app?

Comment: If this app is destined for the iOS App Store, one reason could be that including links to websites where you can buy your products is potentially a violation of the App Store Review Guidelines. (See §3.1.1: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#business). Essentially, if you have something to sell via your app, you have to sell it using In App Purchases, or not at all.

Comment: Thanks, I've expounded on the description a bit. The primary purpose of the app is to sell our core products, but they're asking to add to the app menu a link to a third party website that sells other products. I see this as potentially confusing to users, but I don't have any data to back up my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, good UX is when things go in accordance with user expectations. Bad UX is the opposite.

So, I assume you argue that this is bad UX because users don't expect a button in an app to randomly open a 3rd party website. This is very sensible.

Instead, how about having your button **link to a splash screen inside your app** that features:

- A **short** explanation of the fact that X products are sold on Y (third-party) website
- A button to go to the third-party website (positioned at the bottom)
- As you mentioned: a "link" icon associated with that button to add to the clarity (users may skip over the explanatory paragraph!)
- Standard nav buttons still available to nav back or anywhere else in the app.

The fact is, you HAVE to accomodate a suboptimal flow by linking to an external website. The trade-off of the inefficiency of an "extra" step (a splash screen), outweighs the inefficiency of having a user randomly open a browser tab when they aren't expecting to. So, that's your solution.